# combine JSON service responses using Camel

Tags: json, apache-camel, aggregate, pojo

I have 2 resource based services returning data in JSON format.

The first one is a Order service which returns the order details.This contains orderid and the list of products including the product id and its quantity.

The other is a Product service which returns the product details(description,unit price) of a product whose productid is passed as input to it.

I want to combine these 2 services using a camel route, so that the route response would be a order details along with product details (description,unitprice,quantity,quantity * unitprice) of each product in the order.

Since both services separately return JSON not sure how I can combine them both together to return the final result.

I think I have to  convert each of the services's JSON response to java objects and then compute the details as required , using a POJO and then finally convert the response back to JSON and return the result.

But, not sure if this is the right approach with camel or is there a way to use the indivdual JSON responses directly and combine them and return the responses .

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Take a look at the Content Enricher EIP pattern

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [content-enrich](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) pattern as Claus suggested and then aggregate the response from the product service with the body of the response from the order service.

```
from("direct:in")
    .to("http://order.service:8080")
    .enrich(simple("http:product.service/?productIds=${header.productIds}"), new OrderProductAggregationStrategy());
```

Answer (score -2):

Can't you simply have two routes?

Route 1: Call the order service and send the response to a processor and extract the product id and save it in a header somewhere.

Route 2: Call the product service using the product id found in the header which you got from the previous route. The response here gives you the product details for each product id received in route 2.